# Java polymorphism: Why is this method called last?

Tags: java, polymorphism

i was trying to understand polymorphism in Java better with the following example:

```
public class A {

1 int method(A a) { return 1; }
2 static int method(B b) { return 2 + b.method((A)b); }

}
public class B extends A { 

3 final int method(A a) { return 4 + super.method(a); }
4 int method(C c) { return 8 + this.method((B)c); }

}

public class C extends B {
5 int method(C c) { return 16 + method((A)c); }
}

And, the following declaration, initialization, methodcall:
B b = new B();
b.method(b);
```

I can not wrap my head around, why the "int method(A a) { return 1; }", is the last one to be called.

My train of thought so far:

1. We figure out the static and dynamic Type and of b (B and B)
2. We look in class B, if we find a method called method, which accepts parameter with static type B.
   We find two candidates: 3, 2.
   We call 2, because it requires no implicit casting to the static Type B in the parameter and the static and dynamic types of B are the same.
3. Now figure out the stat/dyn.types for b.method((A) b):
   b is (B/B), and b in the parameter is (A/B) after the cast. Now, we look in class B for a Method called method, which accepts an A-type parameter, we find one,1, but now, because we have a different dynamic type (B), we also need so search B for a possible candidate, we find 3, we use it, since it overrides 1.
4. After that, we discern the types again, because of "super" the static type is the one from the parentclass (A), and the dynamic one: B (the dynamic type of the object which caused the super-call), and A and A for its parameter.
5. So, now we seek in A for a method which accepts an A, we find 1, but the dynamic class is different, so we need to also check for candidates, in class B, which might overwrite the method found in A (1), and use it, if that is the case, which would lead us to calling method 3, again.

But obviously that is not what Java returns, and i do not know where the error to this approach is. In other polymorphism exercises, i came to the correct solution.

Comment: A corner case like this might be of academic interest and surely is important to those implementing a Java compiler and runtime system. To a software engineer using Java, the lesson learned should be to NEVER create such a mess of different methods all with the same name.

Comment: Your conclusion for step 5 is wrong. Method 3 is in the class `B` and the call in method 3 is `super.method(a)`. By using `super` you tell the java runtime explicitly to look for implementations of `method(A a)` in `B`s super classes only.